# Performance gap between the Android Maps application and my application using Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

It's all too well known that with populous overlays, the performance of Google Maps API on Android goes to the dogs. In my application too, an overlay with a ~500-segment path drawn causes the application to pretty much freeze.

I threw some time at recording how the official maps application on Android fares. I did this by creating a similar "My Map" over at maps.google.com and then displaying it as a layer in Maps application. Lo and behold everything worked fine. Now I can't sleep because I want the same thing for my application.

My only guess at this time is the Maps application is using some undocumented/unavailable API. Am I missing something?

Comment: The Maps application does not use `MapView`. The Maps application forked `MapView` and kin a long time ago.